# Existe alguma diferença entre corrotinas, fibras e Green Threads?

Tags: assincronismo, concorrência

Conforme o título da pergunta, vejo esses nomes sendo usados para descrever coisas muito parecidas.

No mundo Python temos *Greenlets* descritos como [corrotinas](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrotina) e *Green Threads*. No mundo Java temos o projeto *Loom* introduzindo fibras. No mundo Kotlin temos corrotinas e bibliotecas como [Quasar](https://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/) (projeto do Ron Pressler atual líder do Projeto Loom) que, entre outras coisas também implementa fibras.

Todas essas construções parecem tocar nos mesmos pontos e chegar no mesmo resultado final. Assíncronicidade e *multitasking* cooperativo que funciona em modo usuário.

Afinal estamos todos falando da mesma coisa? Ou existem diferenças conceituais entre Corrotinas, Fibras e *Green Threads*? Se existem diferenças conceituais, podemos implementar uma coisa através da outra? (E.g., podemos implementar *Green Threads* e Fibras usando corrotinas?).

Comment: PS: Estou criando algumas perguntas para a comunidade. Inicialmente não tenho intenção de responder minhas próprias perguntas (mas posso vir a fazê-lo se as perguntas não atraírem boas respostas). Por favor não se acanhem, a ideia toda é criar boas perguntas para que vocês possam responder :).

Comment: Mais um presente para a comunidade :) eu sei que Java já teve Green Threads (não sei se era o mesmo conceito e intenção, muitas vezes é dado o mesmo nome para conceitos diferentes) e no Ruby também existe algum construto já antigo nessa linha. Aguardando uma daquelas respostas bem informadas :) P.S.: sei de um tal de Turing que tem um bom _spoiler_ para a última pergunta :)

Answer (score 0):

Vejo green threads e fibras como algo um pouco mais "antigo" que corotinas. Quando os sistemas operacionais começaram a suportar threads, uma thread tinha custo quase igual a um processo.

Havia então um interesse de obter as vantagens das threads, porém sem os custos associados, tentando manter o máximo da implementação da thread fora do kernel. O modelo de threading n:m consistia em mapear "n" threads leves para "m" threads do sistema operacional, onde n>m.

Com o tempo, descobriu-se que threads não são panaceia, que tornam desenvolvimento e depuração muito mais complicadas. Os desenvolvedores de sistemas operacionais também notaram que implementar threading n:m é complicado; Linux sempre foi 1:1. Por outro lado, descobriram formas mais eficientes de implementar threads de kernel, mesmo na plataforma x86, o que removeu a motivação do esquema n:m.

O ponto talvez seja que green threads seria um conceito mais próximo do sistema operacional, enquanto corotinas são atreladas à linguagem.